# Jenkins jobs, possible to have jobs being independent of each other?

Tags: jenkins

I was interested to see that there is a pipeline plugin for Jenkins, pretty much what I was looking after.

What I would like to do is that I would like to configure a pipeline "template" where I assign jobs and create individual parameters. The problem is that the way I see how the pipeline plugin works, and Jenkins in general, is that you assign a job to execute another job. This makes the two tightly coupled, right? I would like to have a job named "CleanAndBuild", which I can automatically execute on its own, but I would like to use the job also to be part of a pipeline. The way pipelining and jenkins works, I don't see this being possible? It forces you to create an army of very similar job profiles, right?

Jobs currently seem to work as class instances, whereas it would be nice to have a job "class" and then create several job "class instances" with varying configurations, if you know what I mean...

Comment: "Clean" and "Build" seem like two very related actions in the same build script. That shouldn't be two jenkins jobs, but a single job. If you need to pass parameters to a job (to create an "instance" as you say), use parametrized builds.

Comment: Yes, the clean and build actions are in a same job. But what if you then have a "Deploy" job that deploys and restarts server. You would need to set a "Post Action" on the "CleanAndBuild" job that it triggers the "Deploy" job. Now the two jobs are dependent, you cannot execute the "CleanAndBuild" job without it triggering the "Deploye" job anymore. You would need to create _another_ "CleanAndBuild" job that _only_ does that and does not trigger the "Deploy" job. Is there a way around this? It is a strange limitation to me...

Comment: You want to deploy sometimes without building, and sometimes (but not always) after building? A normal use case I have met is when you always deploy after build, but to different staging environments. Then I'd pass the server to deploy to as a parameter.

Comment: I want to build my application, and sometimes I want to build & deploy. If I set the Build job to always execute the Deploy job (post action), then I can never just Build anymore, it will always execute the Deploy job. This is my problem.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615489/configuring-hudson-to-deploy-a-build

Comment: Not quite. My problem is that there is no "pipeline job" where I would "drag&drop" jobs into placeholders. The pipeline plugin does not act as a "coordinator". The actual coordination must be defined in a job, making jobs tightly coupled. If I want to trigger a flow that only Builds, I have to create a job for that. If I want to create a flow that builds AND deploys, I have to create another Build job, because the previously defined build job ALWAYS executes the deployment in the end. Jobs are tightly coupled. There is no "task"/"pipeline" that would coordinate events.

Comment: If you have job 1 "build, job 2 "deploy last build" (via deploy plugin), and a third job that runs both in sequence to form "build and deploy", then at least you only have one configured build job.